# "npm install googleapis" produces the following error

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

"npm install googleapis" produces the following error:

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: inherits@'^2.0.1'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["1.0.0","2.0.0","2.0.1"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:553:10)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:477:15
npm ERR!     at saved (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:218:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (OS X 10.9.4). What turned out to be the problem was a dated node/npm installation, which I upped to the latest version from the node.js homepage. Not sure if node or npm is the culprit, but upgrading both fixed the problem you describe.